# SOAP services testing - special characters in xml response

Tags: soap, karate

I am trying to test SOAP services using Karate. By referring to the documentation on git, i was able to setup my project and make some soap features. I am running into an issue during assertion as the response has special chars. Below are the details:

**SOAP XML Response:**

```
<Reason Number="1">
    <ReasonText>T12345</ReasonText>
</Reason>
```

**SOAP Raw Response:**

```
&lt;ReasonText&gt;T844&lt;/ReasonText&gt;
```

I am able to successfully assert using following in karate feature:

```
* def actualResponse = response
* match actualResponse contains '&lt;ReasonText&gt;T12345&lt;/ReasonText&gt;'
```

Unable to assert while using below:

```
* def actualResponse = response
* match actualResponse contains '<ReasonText>T12345</ReasonText>'
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score -1):

There's something very wrong somewhere. And I have no idea what you mean by "SOAP Raw Response". If the server is actually returning what you are saying, then it is a problem with the server, not Karate.

Since no one else has reported this, I'm 99.9% sure you have a problem in your environment. Please take the help of someone from the server-side team if necessary.

EDIT: for those landing here in the future, please see these other answers for ideas:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043998/143475

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60122951/143475

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Peter. By SOAP Raw response, i mean the Raw response that we can view in SOAP UI tool. Do you think sharing my karate-config.js helps? Please let me know if any additional information like headers i am passing helps.

Comment: @Uday that "raw response" is not even valid XML. and I have no idea about SOPA UI, please don't bring it into the discussion. since you have not provided any useful info, the only advice I have left is this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I will work on submitting an issue. While i am on it, can you check below please.

karate-config.js:

    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 40000);
    karate.configure('readTimeout', 40000);
    karate.configure('logPrettyRequest', true);
    karate.configure('logPrettyResponse', true);
    karate.configure('ssl',true);


Headers that i am passing:
* def req_headers = {Authorization: '#(token)', Content-Type: 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',SOAPAction: '""' }


partial response listed on my idea terminal after executing the test:

&lt;ReasonText&gt;T12345&lt;/ReasonText&gt;

Comment: Anyway i can write/save the response from the webservice to a file so that i can include/inspect the response thoroughly? Appreciate if you can point me to an example.