# Match html response in karate

Tags: karate

I hava a problem in matching my response errors with html.

I tried like this

- match $.errors == '#present'
- match $.errors == response

Errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: Unexpected object!</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm doing it like this and the scnario will be stoped!

```
When method post
* if (responseStatus == 500 ) karate.abort()
  Then status 200
* match $.errors == '#notpresent'
```

How can I do to get the response match as html text?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Karate only works with well-formed XML. You can try to replace content in the HTML to clean it up. Or you can just do string `contains` matches etc. Or you can write some JS or Java code for custom checks.

This will work (after removing the `<meta>` tag which is not well-formed.

```
* def response =
"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: Unexpected object!</pre>
</body>
</html>
"""
* match //pre == 'Error: Unexpected object!'
```