# trying to do assertion on SSE type content type

Tags: api, assert, karate

```
Scenario: Test
* def contentType = 'text/event-stream'
* def response =
"""
<data contentLength="5930" contentType="text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"><![CDATA[
data:
}
}
```

> ## This works and asserts correctly but this is contains and i would need to have the value known beforehand
>
> And match jsonresponse.data._ contains '00000000000000000000abc'
>
> ## This works and fails correctly but this is contains and i would need to have the value known beforehand
>
> And match jsonresponse.data._ contains '123456789'

## Is there a way where i can get the value for groundNumber and other attribute from this json.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert that stuff into a valid JSON. Refer type conversion: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

For the given response, this will convert the multiple rows into a single JSON array.

```
* def data = /data
* print data
* def data = data.replaceAll('data:', '').replaceAll('}', '},')
* json data = '[' + data + ']'
* print data
```

Now you can do normal JsonPath processing.

```
* def numbers = $data[*].groundNumber
* match numbers == ['00000000000000000000123', '00000000000000000000456', '00000000000000000000789', '00000000000000000000000']
```

Comment: wow, it probably took me longer to write the question than you to answer.
amazing!
i still don't how it's working but i will try to reverse engineer it